# Pass a list of parameters in read.table( )

Tags: r, read.table

```
filepath <- paste0("path")
parameters <- list(header=T,row.names=1,sep="\t",check.names=F,stringsAsFactors=F)
input<- read.table(filepath,parameters)
```

However, I got a error message says:

> Error in !header : invalid argument type

It works fine when the parameters are not put in the list like

```
filepath <- paste0("path")
input <- read.table(filepath,header=T,row.names=1,sep="\t",check.names=F,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Since I am importing many data and the parameters are the same,I am wondering how I can pass the parameters in the `read.table` function.

Comment: Didn't see your comment, quick draw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `do.call`. It allows you to provide a list of arguments. Add `filepath` to the parameters variable:

```
do.call(read.table, c(filepath, parameters))
```